# Groovy can use a subscript on an XSSFSheet in the simple console, but in IntelliJ it can't

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I have a variable of this type:`XSSFSheet sheet` (I'm using apache-poi to read from Excel).

In the simple groovy console I can do `sheet[4][5]` to access a certain cell by coordinates. When I try the same thing in IntelliJ, it gives me the exception that

```
No signature of method: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getRow(int), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), last(), first()
```

I looked in the reference and indeed, XSSFSheet can't be indexed by an int. But why then it is possible in the simple groovy console that comes with it? Can I do the same in IntelliJ?

Comment: and with intellij you mean what exactly?  you having a project with a groovy-all.jar in the classpath?  is this version of groovy radically different than the one you are using for the shell?  and have you tried `sheet['4'][5]`?

Comment: sheet['4'][5] doesn't work either.
After I added groovy-all.jar, it says: `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$NodeXobj.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/store/Xobj$NodeXobj, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature`

Comment: I haave a gradle project in IntelliJ, groovy installed and configured, so I read that I don't need the groovy-all jar.

Comment: yes you don't.  should have said gradle in the first place or is it really only not working in intellij (e.g. it works with `gradle run` in command line)?  now what version of groovy are you using in gradle and which one for the shell?

Comment: 2.3.7 in both of them. But look here, the API doesn't specify a getAt method at all. Then how come in the groovy console I can index it with an int, does groovy somehow figure it out and makes some magic?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, and I'm only answering because I was wondering the same thing you asked in your last comment and found the answer trying to understand.

As you mention in your last comment, the subscript operator in groovy translates to the `getAt()` method, and as you say, the XSSFSheet class doesn't have such a method *in java*.

Since it can indeed be called from groovy, it does exist somewhere. With a bit of metaprogramming, we get the following:

```
def getAt = org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.metaClass.getMetaMethod("getAt", [java.lang.Integer] as Class[])
println getAt

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$240@e7edb54[name: getAt params: [int] returns: class java.lang.Object owner: interface java.lang.Iterable]
```

Which means it comes from the `Iterable` interface. And still, this is not true *in java*. But groovy adds many methods to standard java classes, and indeed we can see [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html) that it adds a `getAt()` method to `Iterable`.

This doesn't answer your original question (why doesn't it work in your IntelliJ ? it should and it does here), but it answers a question in the comments. I would have posted it there, but I lack reputation.